# Insert element into XML using XQuery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I need to insert a column in a stored procedure which reads XML as input and reads the XML value using XQuery in SQL Server.

Consider a table dbo.emailDetails

```
Create Table dbo.emailDetails
(
     EmailId int,
     HomeEmail varchar(250),
);
```

XML file:

```
<EmailDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EmailId>1</EmailId>
    <HomeEmail>test@sample.com</HomeEmail>
</EmailDetails>
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [apply].[UpdateEmailDetails]
     @EmailDetails XML
 (DOCUMENT [dbo].[EmailDetails])
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EmailId INT, @HomeEmail NVARCHAR(250)

    SET @HomeEmail = @EmailDetails.value(N'(//EmailDetails/HomeEmail)[1]',N'NVARCHAR(255)');
    SET @EmailId = @EmailDetails.value(N'(//EmailDetails/EmailID)[1]',N'INT');

    INSERT INTO dbo.emails (emailid, homeemail) 
    VALUES (@EmailId, @HomeEmail )
END
```

Now I would like to include the `IsConfirmed` in the above stored procedure.

```
 alter table dbo.Emaildetails
    add IsConfirmed bit not null default 0

----- Executed successfully and added the new column in the table.
```

While I tried the below changes in the stored procedure:

```
Declare @IsConfirmed bit
SET @IsConfirmed = @EmailDetails.value(N'(//EmailDetails/IsConfirmed)[1]',N'BIT');
```

and got the error:

> XQuery [value()]: There is no element named 'IsConfirmed' in the type 'element(EmailDetails,#anonymous) *'.

Could someone help me with this?

Kindly let me know if any details required further.

Regards,
Viswa V.

Comment: Looks like your variable naming is all over the place in your example, you have variables named "@ContactDetails" in your SP which don't exist, "//EmailDetails/IslConfirmed)[1]" has an incorrect node name, " INSERT INTO dbo.emails" has the wrong table name. Other than that when you tidy it up it works fine, are you sure you aren't missing showing us something else?

Comment: Hi Jamie, Sorry about the typo.  I have edited the page. I want to know the  syntax for my Input XMl mentioning as (Document <TableName>). I dont know much about XML. Could you please help me to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure has an input parameter which is as follows:

```
@EmailDetails XML (DOCUMENT [dbo].[EmailDetails])
```

This means you have an XML Schema Collection named "[dbo].[EmailDetails]" defined which basically says what format the incoming XML should be in.

If you expand the Programmability > Types > XML Schema Collections nodes in your database explorer you will see your "[dbo].[EmailDetails]" schema. If you then right click and select Script as > Create to new window you will see what nodes are expected to be in the XML you pass to your procedure.

You need to ALTER this schema to include a definition for your new

```
<IsConfirmed>
```

node.

Once you alter it you should then be able to run your alter procedure command again.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187856.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) MSDN article explains more on the topic

Comment: Hi Jamie, Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. You catched up my requirements and provided solution accurately. This works like a charm! Million thanks to you! :)